# Retrieving a threaded comment list recursively

Tags: python, recursion, functional-programming, reddit, praw

I am trying to write a recursive function that can retrieve the nested comments from a Reddit submission. I am using Python + PRAW

```
def _get_comments(comments, ret = []):
    for comment in comments:
        if len(comment._replies) > 0:
            return _get_comments(tail(comments), ret + [{
                #"body": comment.body,
                "id": comment.id,
                "author": str(comment.author),
                "replies": map(lambda replies: _get_comments(replies, []), [comment._replies])
                }])
        else:
            return ret + [{
                    #"body": comment.body,
                    "id": comment.id,
                    "author": str(comment.author)
                }]
    return ret

def tail(list):
    return list[1:len(list)]
```

And I get the following output, which is incomplete and has nested arrays:

```
pprint(_get_comments(s.comments))
[{'author': 'wheremydirigiblesat',
  'id': u'ctuzo4x',
  'replies': [[{'author': 'rhascal',
                'id': u'ctvd6jw',
                'replies': [[{'author': 'xeltius', 'id': u'ctvx1vq'}]]}]]},
 {'author': 'DemiDualism',
  'id': u'ctv54qs',
  'replies': [[{'author': 'rhascal',
                'id': u'ctv5pm1',
                'replies': [[{'author': 'blakeb43', 'id': u'ctvdb9c'}]]}]]},
 {'author': 'Final7C', 'id': u'ctvao9j'}]
```

The `Submission` object has a `comments` attribute which is a list of `Comment` objects. Each `Comment` object has a `_replies` attribute which is a list of more `Comment`s.

What am I missing? I gave it my best shot -- recursion is hard.

Comment: [My testing Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TrueAskReddit/comments/3g57z2/why_are_humans_fascinated_by_ascending_pertaining/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it almost correctly. The problem is that you're trying to make recursion as something complex, when it's simple. You don't need `tail()` function as well as `map()` function inside, since you're already iterating through comments.

I renamed your function in examples, since it converts comments to dicts actually.

Let's start from simple case, think about it like: "okey, I want to have a function, which is able to convert list of comments to list of dicts". Just simple function:

```
def comments_to_dicts(comments):
    results = []  # create list for results
    for comment in comments:  # iterate over comments
        item = {
            "id": comment.id,
            "author": comment.author,
        }  # create dict from comment

        results.append(item)  # add converted item to results 
    return results  # return all converted comments
```

And now you want dict to also include list of replies converted to dicts. And you already have function, which is able to do this conversion, so let's just use it and put result into `item['replies']`:

```
def comments_to_dicts(comments):
    results = []  # create list for results
    for comment in comments:  # iterate over comments
        item = {
            "id": comment.id,
            "author": comment.author,
        }  # create dict from comment

        if len(comment._replies) > 0:
            item["replies"] = comments_to_dicts(comment._replies)  # convert replies using the same function

        results.append(item)  # add converted item to results 
    return results  # return all converted comments
```

Since you modified the same function you call, it will convert all replies, no matter how deep they are. Hope it's more clear how recursion works.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is very clear, compared to how over-complicated I was making it!